# Laravel list() with each() function error with deprecated function

Tags: php, laravel-4

I get a little confuse here on how to alternatively replace the each() function since it was deprecated and I'm aware of that and fixed some of the `while( list() = each() )` error case in my project. However, what other option should I use for this case:

```
foreach($new_id as $new_ids) {
    list($key,$valueAddress) = each($address);
    list($key,$valueCity) = each($city);
    list($key,$valueState) = each($state);
    if(isset($_POST['publicOnly'])) {
        list($key,$valuePublicOnly) = each($publicOnly);
    } else {
        $valuePublicOnly = 0;
    }

    $propertyAddress = PropertyAddressManagement::find($new_ids);
        $propertyAddress->address = $valueAddress;
        $propertyAddress->city = $valueCity;
        $propertyAddress->state = $valueState;
        $propertyAddress->publicOnly = $valuePublicOnly;
    $propertyAddress->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the keys so just get the current value and then move to the next one:

```
foreach($new_id as $new_ids) {
    $propertyAddress = PropertyAddressManagement::find($new_ids);
        $propertyAddress->address = current($address);
        $propertyAddress->city = current($city);
        $propertyAddress->state = current($state);
        $propertyAddress->publicOnly = isset($_POST['publicOnly']) ? current($publicOnly) : 0;
    $propertyAddress->save();

    next($address); next($city); next($state); next($publicOnly);
}
```

However, if the keys are the same in all of the array then I think really this should work:

```
foreach($new_id as $key => $new_ids) {
    $propertyAddress = PropertyAddressManagement::find($new_ids);
        $propertyAddress->address = $address[$key];
        $propertyAddress->city = $city[$key];
        $propertyAddress->state = $state[$key];
        $propertyAddress->publicOnly = isset($_POST['publicOnly']) ? $publicOnly[$key] : 0;
    $propertyAddress->save();
}
```

Comment: i tried this.. though it ended up in this error message: `next() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Comment: i still got this `next()` problem. though i found out that the page was saving.

Comment: Sorry, the second example doesn't need next.

Comment: i see. your answer worked finally. i get carried away after seeing the text editor was empty.  :| Appreciate your help and Thank you sir!