# Laravel conditional statement with each() result error

Tags: php, laravel-4

Partly confused (still) because the variable `$investment_type` resulting of "**Creating default object from empty value**" when I follow this previous question of mine [Laravel list() with each() function error with deprecated function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631553/laravel-list-with-each-function-error-with-deprecated-function).

This is the original code.

```
$assetsData = ClientPropertyManagement::find($assets_id);
$investmentType = Input::get('investmenttype'.$assets_id);
$legalname = Input::get('legalname'.$assets_id);
$ownership = Input::get('ownership'.$assets_id);
$tic = Input::get('tic'.$assets_id);
$entity_id = Input::get('entity_id'.$assets_id);

foreach($investmentType as $investment_type) {

    list($key,$value) = each($legalname);
    list($key,$valueOwner) = each($ownership);
    list($key,$valueTic) = each($tic);
    list($key,$valueEntityId) = each($entity_id);

    if($valueEntityId == 0) {
      $assetEntity = new ClientEntityManagement;
      $assetEntity->property_id = $assetsData->property_id;
      $assetEntity->client_id = $id;
    } else {
      $assetEntity = ClientEntityManagement::find($valueEntityId);
    }

    $assetEntity->investment_type = $investment_type;
    $assetEntity->entity_name = $value;
    $assetEntity->ownership = $valueOwner;
    $assetEntity->ticnum = $valueTic;
    $assetEntity->save();

}
```

Here's what I did in my code.

```
foreach( $investmentType as $key => $investment_type ) {

    $assetEntity->investment_type = $investment_type;

    $assetEntity->entity_name = $legalname[$key];
    $assetEntity->ownership = $ownership[$key];
    $assetEntity->ticnum = $tic[$key];

    if ( $entity_id[$key] == 0 ) {
        $assetEntity = new ClientEntityManagement;
        $assetEntity->property_id = $assetsData->property_id;
        $assetEntity->client_id = $id;                  
    } else {
        $assetEntity = ClientEntityManagement::find($investment_type);
    }

    $assetEntity->save();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$assetEntity` isn't created yet, and you are trying to use as an object. To solve that, you need to change the position where you instantiate the object and create the variable `$assetEntity`:

```
foreach( $investmentType as $key => $investment_type ) {

   if ( $entity_id[$key] == 0 ) {
        $assetEntity = new ClientEntityManagement;
        $assetEntity->property_id = $assetsData->property_id;
        $assetEntity->client_id = $id;                  
    } else {
        $assetEntity = ClientEntityManagement::find($investment_type);
    }

    $assetEntity->investment_type = $investment_type;

    $assetEntity->entity_name = $legalname[$key];
    $assetEntity->ownership = $ownership[$key];
    $assetEntity->ticnum = $tic[$key];

    $assetEntity->save();

}
```

That way `$assetEntity` will be created, and then you populate the other attributes.

Also, you may want to use the IoC Container and replace the `new ClientEntityManagement` with `App::make('ClientEntityManagement')`. Read more at https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc

Comment: no it's not working... i still receive "Creating default object from empty value"... and it looks like the `$investmentType` is returning "null"...

Comment: Which line @iMarkDesigns ?

Comment: this line `$assetEntity->investment_type = $investment_type;` but the weird thing is, when I press Enter to the address-bar, it does save the output I did from the page even if it will not display the success/error parameter.